# Bottom content hidden by keyboard with Flutter screenUtil & persistent nav bar:

Tags: flutter

I am using this 2 packages:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil
https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

The problem is when I have bottom content and I press the keyboard, The content got hidden like picture below. [image][image]

PS: Itreid using Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom));
and resizetoavoidbottominset but did not work for me.

The problem is I have a lot of code separated In different files I will try to put the global architecture here:

```
ScreenUtilInit(
  designSize: const Size(screenWidth, screentHeight),
  minTextAdapt: true,
  splitScreenMode: true,
  useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
  builder: (_, child) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      
      home: MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AccountBloc(),
        ),
      ], child: const MyApp()),
    );
  },
)
return PersistentTabView(
  context,
  controller: controller,
  screens: buildScreens(),
  items: navBarsItems(),
  confineInSafeArea: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  stateManagement: true,
  hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
  decoration: NavBarDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
  ),
  popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
  popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
  itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    curve: Curves.ease,
  ),
  screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
    animateTabTransition: true,
    curve: Curves.ease,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  ),
  navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I hope this can help future users:

go to PersistentTabView and remove this code

```
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
```